# Continuous Month in Tableau Showing Month + Year

Tags: tableau-api

I changed my Month dimension in the columns row to 'Continuous' and instead of the axis just showing the Year it broke by Month + Year. Which is not the desired result. When I review videos when changing Month to 'Continuous' the axis automatically changes to year [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015] but when I do it I result in [December 2013, June 2014, December 2014, June 2015...].

I need just the years. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: could you please upload before and after screenshots of your scenario to provide more context?

Comment: Right click on the field and change the format.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new calculated field and place it in the view -

```
YEAR([Date])
```